# What exactly is the web.Site.SystemAccount?

Tags: sharepoint

I'm quite sure, the answer must be somewhere but I googled my ass off:

I know that "elevated privilegues" runs with the appPool-Account. But what account is used for

`web.Site.SystemAccount` in SharePoint? Is it the farm admin?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN documentation says that

> [SPSite.SystemAccount](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsite.systemaccount(v=office.15).aspx) Gets the system account of the site collection

In addition, Reflector says that `SystemAccount` user ID is `1073741823` that corresponds to `SHAREPOINT\system`:

```
<m:properties>
    <d:Id m:type="Edm.Int32">1073741823</d:Id>
    <d:IsHiddenInUI m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IsHiddenInUI>
    <d:LoginName>SHAREPOINT\system</d:LoginName>
    <d:Title>System Account</d:Title>
    <d:PrincipalType m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:PrincipalType>
    <d:Email></d:Email>
    <d:IsShareByEmailGuestUser m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IsShareByEmailGuestUser>
    <d:IsSiteAdmin m:type="Edm.Boolean">false</d:IsSiteAdmin>
    <d:UserId m:type="SP.UserIdInfo">
    <d:NameId>S-1-0-0</d:NameId>
    <d:NameIdIssuer>urn:office:idp:activedirectory</d:NameIdIssuer>
    </d:UserId>
</m:properties>
```

Answer (score 0):

this account is the **primary administrator** of Site collection which you can configure from Central admin.

I am afraid the RUNwithElevatedPrivileges is run by System account not app pool account. Because normally we use a separate app pool account than site collection administrator. If you debug the code and get SPContext with in RWEP... you will get System account syntax.

below article is explaining .

```
[http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1022][1]
```